# swift 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported type: NSURL (found in field AccountTypeImageURL)'

Tags: swift, xcode, google-cloud-firestore

When I upload a picture from my phone the app crashes and i get the error

> 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported type: NSURL (found
>   in field AccountTypeImageURL)'

here is my function containing the relevant code

```
    func submitButtonADD(){

        let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("Account Type Images").child("\(imageName)png")
        let sRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("Account Type Images").child("\(imageName)png")
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }



        if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.profileImageView.image!) {


            storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }


               sRef.downloadURL { url2, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error)
                    } else {
                        // Get the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'




                    let db = Firestore.firestore()

                    db.collection("Users").document(uid).setData(["AccountTypeImageURL": url2],merge: true)


                }
            }

            })
        }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error is telling you exactly what is wrong you are trying to save an `NSURL` type in a `Firestore` document which is not supported. So convert the url to string and then save it in Firestore like this:

```
db.collection("Users").document(uid).setData(["AccountTypeImageURL": url2.absoluteString],merge: true)
```